# To delete WSO2 EI 6.6.0 Server log file automatically regardless of size by using log4j2.properties file

Tags: wso2, log4j, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to delete WSO2 EI 6.6.0 Carbon log files automatically by using log4j2.

**Constraint**: Except last 14days, all log files needs to be deleted automatically regardsless of file size.

Log4j2.properties file:

[image: log4j2.properties file]

I checked below, none of them works for me.

1. [Ref Link 1](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/11633) - unfortunately not deleting any files.
2. [Ref Link 2](http://mycodeideas.blogspot.com/2016/10/how-to-limit-wso2-service-log-file-size.html) - taking some backup file like wso2carbon.log.1, wso2carbon.log.2 in addition to existing files, nothing will be deleted.
3. [Ref Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67898077/how-can-i-automatically-delete-old-log-files-in-wso2-esb-and-ei) - not working this too.

Note: added log4j2.properties file of WSO2 EI 6.6.0.

Outcome: None of files are deleted.

Kindly WSO2 Experts look into this and provide me a exact solution for this?

Comment: Can you add your Log4j2 configuration file to your question and can you run your server with `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` and add the logs concerning Log4j2 initiatization?

Comment: Hi @Piotr P. Karwasz,
I have added log4j2.properties file details attached in above question as you requested. Kindly have a look on this.